# How to do single select in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Im using write_xlsx gem and having multiple select in excel(written in vba) and now i want single select in only one cell.

Is it possible to do with data_validation? or i have to modify with vba?

```
worksheet.data_validation('D2',
{
 :validate => 'list',
 :value    => ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
})
```

Thanks

Comment: What about `:value    => ['One']`?

Comment: @SangbokLee:  ['One', 'Two', 'Three'] is the dropdown value from that i want to select any one value